# Send form data from controller to screen on AirConsole

Tags: airconsole

If i have a form with 3 differents textfields on controller.html, it's possible to send the data of the 3 elements with a "send button" to my screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending a form would basically work the same as you would do it the usual way in javascript:

1. Catch the form submission via the `onsubmit` event
2. Get the input values and send them via `airconsole.message`

Something like this:

```
    var form_ele = document.getElementById("form");

    form_ele.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var input_1_val = your_input_element.value;
        airconsole.message(AirConsole.SCREEN, { 
            input_1: input_1_val,
            // other key values
        };
    });
```

An AirConsole controller is nothing else than a (mobile) website.